# Numeric Values and Special charectors in str_word_count function

Tags: php

I want to numeric values and special charectors values in str_word_count()
so how can do that.

example:

```
$str = str_word_count("B2B my78:test@ Number&10",1);
print_r($str);
```

Output

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => B
> [1] => B
> [2] => my
> [3] => test
> [4] => Number
> ```
>
> )

but I want to Out put Like this

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => B2B
> [1] => my78:test@
> [2] => Number&10
> ```
>
> )

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, could you clarify? To get the desired output from the example above, you'd use `explode(' ', $str)` but I'm guessing that's not what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Hey, I dont know your exact goal, but i added another example where preg match all acts just like str word count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**preg_match_all** behaves almost like **st_word_count**, in that it can return the number of matches and an array of words in your string.  By using it, you can have the utmost flexibility in defining what exactly constitutes a "word."

```
$count = preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z0-9@&:]+/', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: yes, but its only count word and in str_word_count function also display word by parameter 1.

Comment: The words are returned in an array by reference in $matches, so it is like both version of strwordcount all in one function.

Answer (score 2):

The [php.net documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) shows a very nice example of doing that, so I modified it to fit your example:

```
$str = "B2B my-78:test@ Number&10";
$array = str_word_count($str, 1, '1234567890:@&');
```

But you can use regular expressions or `explode` if you need more customized results.

Comment: if i want to all special charector so how can do that?

Comment: Don't use this function.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_split('/\s+/', $str)` perhaps?

Comment: That's a very sophisticated sibling to `explode(' ', $str);` right?

Comment: thanks for help but I want to use in str_word_count()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$str = "B2B my-78:test@ Number&10";
$array = explode(' ', $str);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
?>
```

-
Thanks