# PHP: str_word_count not working on my string, anyone see the error?

Tags: php, string, count, words

I have a string "34_56_67_78_97 34_56_67_78_97 23_45_56_67_89 34_56_77_88_96 45_56_66_78_88 56_67_67_78_90" but when I run the code below the array comes back as null. The numbers linked with hyphens are a numerical word from my point of view and I would like to know which numerical words appear in the string 2 or more times. In this case the answer would be the numerical word 34_56_67_78_97.

```
$string="34_56_67_78_97 34_56_67_78_97 23_45_56_67_89 34_56_77_88_96 45_56_66_78_88 56_67_67_78_90"

$words = str_word_count($string, 1);

$frequency = array_count_values($words);

$result = array_filter($frequency, function ($x) { return $x >= 13; });
```

Comment: what does `str_word_count()` do??

Comment: str_word_count counts how many times the individual words in a string occur.

Comment: Where did you get the idea from that numbers and underscores were considered words? Did you check the manual on str_word_count?

Answer (score 0):

Found a link to the question here at stackoverflow:
[Numeric Values and Special charectors in str_word_count function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538719/numeric-values-and-special-charectors-in-str-word-count-function)

So my code should look like this to make it work:

```
$str="34_56_67_78_97 34_56_67_78_97 23_45_56_67_89 34_56_77_88_96 45_56_66_78_88 56_67_67_78_90";
$somearray = str_word_count($str, 1, '1234567890:@&_');
print_r($somearray);
```

Print out of code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 34_56_67_78_97
    [1] => 34_56_67_78_97
    [2] => 23_45_56_67_89
    [3] => 34_56_77_88_96
    [4] => 45_56_66_78_88
    [5] => 56_67_67_78_90
)
```